# I'm trying to add a user from a SharePoint List into a group in Active Directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

In my SharePoint List I have the user email address and I'm adding in the user to a group in Active Directory. I try to trim everything from the @ symbol in the email address and get the user from the SharePoint List and add the user into the Active Directory group.

I get the following errors

```
Connect-SPOService : Could not connect to SharePoint Online.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-SPOService -Url https://capsticks-admin.sharepoint.com/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ConnectSPOService
 
-credential : The term '-credential' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:12
+            -credential SharepointOnline1@Internal.Capsticks.com
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-credential:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:8 char:16
+ $spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
+                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:9 char:1
+ $spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$ListName]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:11 char:47
+ $spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['ID'] -eq 1}
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Get-PnPListItem : The current connection holds no SharePoint context. Please use one of the Connect-PnPOnline commands which uses the -Url argument to connect.
At line:14 char:14
+ ... ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "Submitter Email" ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PnPListItem], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetListItem
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:22 char:2
+  $submitteremail = $ListItems.FieldValues["Approver Email"];
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:2
+  $submitteremail = $submitteremail.TrimEnd("@","");
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
At line:34 char:65
+ ... upMember -identity "Wireless Access - Users" -Members $submitteremail
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
 


Cannot index into a null array.
At line:38 char:2
+  $ListItem["Department"] = "IT"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The Below is my PowerShell Script.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://ADUsers.sharepoint.com/ -credential Admin@outlook.com
           
#Config Variables
$SiteURL="https://sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet-IT/Lists/MimeCast%20Access%20Form%20Responses?env=WebViewList"
$ListName= "MimeCast Access Form Responses"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$ListName]

$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['ID'] -eq 1}

#sharepoint online pnp powershell get list items
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "Submitter Email" -PageSize 2000

#Loop through Items that have 1 in the Bit Column
$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['Approved'] = 1
}

#Set Variables
 $submitteremail = $ListItems.FieldValues["Approver Email"];
 
 $submitteremail = $submitteremail.TrimEnd("@","")
 
 #Loop through Submitter emails
 Foreach ($item in $submitteremail)
 {
     #Get the List Item's Submitter email
    Write-host $Item["Submitter email"]
 }
 
 #Add username into AD Group 
 Add-ADGroupMember -identity "Wireless Access - Users" -Members $submitteremail
 

 #Set "Department" column value
 $ListItem["Department"] = "IT"
```

Comment: `Connect-SPOService -Url https://ADUsers.sharepoint.com/ -credential Admin@outlook.com` should all be on the same line

Comment: Why you mix SharePoint Server, SharePoint Online and PowerShell PnP commands? This script is a complete non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out is Get-SPWeb is part of Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module. Make sure this module is installed properly

```
install-module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Comment: Absolutely not! Get-SPWeb is for SharePoint Server on-premise. `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` module has commands like `Get-SPOSite` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Apologies, this was an oversight. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Okay Sorry @jleture  I'm new to PowerShell, I'm just trying to find a way on what the best way would be to get the users from a SharePoint List into a group in Active Directory.