# How do I get users from a SharePoint List and add assign it to a group in Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint List that is working with Power Automate and I need to get the Users from a SharePoint List and add it into Active Directory. I have thought about using PowerShell any ideas please. I am new to PowerShell.

So I have tried this command and it works. I need a way where I can grab the Useernames from a SharePoint List and assign it to a group in PowerShell. So I need a way maybe where it loops through the list and adds it into Active Directory.

```
 Add-ADGroupMember -identity "Wireless Access - Users" -Members mrtumble
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kushal. This seems to be the same question that was asked yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77517346/447901 Have you worked through the responses there? SO is a place to make broken code work. This question has only working code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to this:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com


$users = Get-SPOListItem -ListName "User List"


foreach ($user in $users) {
    $username = $user["Username"]
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Wireless Access - Users" -Members $username
}
```